# Change GridView Items size

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

I want to implement two functions:

1. Change GirdView to Listview.
2. Users can change items size.

> Both I have achieved, but have a problems of the combination

In xaml, I have two `ItemsPanelTemplate`:

```
<!--Two mode-->
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsStackPanelTemplate">
        <ItemsStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsWrapGridTemplate">
        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

In code, I have a button to change views:

```
if(Viewstatus == "GridView")
{
    //now it is gridview, then change to listview
    girdView.ItemsPanel = this.Resources["ItemsStackPanelTemplate"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;
    girdView.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["listviewdata"] as DataTemplate;
    Viewstatus = "ListView";
}
else
{
    girdView.ItemsPanel = this.Resources["ItemsWrapGridTemplate"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;
    girdView.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["BookDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
    Viewstatus = "GridView";
}
```

And I have a change size function code (`myTitle` is a object that save some status):

```
ItemsWrapGrid appItemsPanel = (ItemsWrapGrid)girdView.ItemsPanelRoot;
if(myTitle != null)
{
    appItemsPanel.ItemWidth = myTitle.ZoomValue;
    appItemsPanel.ItemHeight = myTitle.ZoomValue + 20;
    zoom = myTitle.ZoomValue;
}
```

Both of two is normal, but when I changed views, I can't change size;

> Because when I changed GridView's ItemsPanel, my GridView's ItemsPanelRoot is to be null.

So I can't get `girdView.ItemsPanelRoot`.

How do I do? How can I have both two functions? and my way is wrong?

**Update: Thanks marked answer.**

But I have a new problem:

In changeView method I have code had problem:

```
if(Viewstatus == "GridView")
{
    //now it is gridview, then change to listview
    girdView.ItemsPanel = this.Resources["ItemsStackPanelTemplate"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;
    girdView.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["listviewdata"] as DataTemplate;
    IEnumerable<Grid> items = VisualTreeHelperClass.FindVisualChildren<Grid>(girdView);
    foreach (var item in itemsa)
    {
        if(item.Name == "myGrid")
            item.Width = myTitle.Framesize;
    }
    Viewstatus = "ListView";
}
else
{
    girdView.ItemsPanel = this.Resources["ItemsWrapGridTemplate"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;
    girdView.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["BookDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
    Viewstatus = "GridView";
}
```

And I failed.(`myGrid` is Grid Name in Template,If I don't do this, It will change all width of View. I trid to delete that `if(item.Name == "myGrid")`, It change some other view's width, I saw that in Debug.WriteLine)

> But I have another method, I invoke that method to run same code, It is work.

**So I think**:

If I change view and I find child of view immediately(Two Things in one method), I will failed.

If I change view, I do something to invoke another method, It will work.

I tried to use:

```
public void ChangeView(){
    //code that change view
    .........
    ChangeSize();
}
public void ChangeSize(){
    //find child and change size code
}
```

doesn't work too.

I think, if I want change size, change size code must Have nothing to do with
change view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because when I changed GridView's ItemsPanel, my GridView's ItemsPanelRoot is to be null.

If you changed the `ItemsPanel` of `GridView`, the `ItemsPanel` become a  `ItemsStackPanel` object, not a `ItemsWrapGrid` object. So that you cannot get a `ItemsWrapGrid` object, but GridView's `ItemsPanelRoot` is not null, it is a `ItemsStackPanel`.

```
ItemsStackPanel appItemsPanel = (ItemsStackPanel)girdView.ItemsPanelRoot;
```

> Change GridVew Items size

But the `ItemsStackPanel` doesn't have properties to set item height and width directly that `ItemsWrapGrid` had. Actually no matter which `ItemsPanel` it is set currently, you always could use [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper) to get  `GridViewItem`s and setting height and width properties. For example:

```
private void btnchangesize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<GridViewItem> items = FindVisualChildren<GridViewItem>(girdView);
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        item.Height = 80;
        item.Width = 100;
    }  
}
private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I mean, If when APP is started, the `GridVIew.ItemsPanel ` is a `ItemsWrapGrid`,Now I can get `ItemsPanelRoot` object.And then I change to List mode,as you said, `ItemsPanel` will be a `ItemsStackPanel`,but now `ItemsPanelRoot` is already null.I saw that through the debug of VS(I maybe wrong).Then I change it back, `ItemsPanel ` is a `ItemsWrapGrid`,the `ItemsPanelRoot` is null too, I don't know why.I want let users change size in `ItemsWrapGrid` mode only,but I can't get object through`ItemsWrapGrid appItemsPanel=(ItemsWrapGrid)girdView.ItemsPanelRoot;` when I had changed it back.

Comment: I have solved it, you are right, have some Exceptional case

Comment: Sorrry, I have another problem: When I changed `GridVIew.ItemsPanel` in a method, Then I try to Get `ItemsPanelRoot`(code is  in this method), It is Null.And I get `ItemsPanelRoot` in other method, it is normal....And I use your code to find item, it failed(code is in that method too). But I use your code to find them in other method is normal. Why,? I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: @haihanjin, so what is that special method? Can you tell more details about what differences between that method and other normal methods?

Comment: I had update my problem, and I write my status in that, Thanks very much